# ActionBarSherlock tab selection

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, selection

Is there a way to call the select method on an action bar sherlock tab without actually selecting it? The end goal is to avoid triggering the tab listeners (`onTabSelected`, etc), and only make the layout change so that the tab in question looks like it has been pressed?

Similarly, is there a way to trigger a swipe so that the swipe is performed, but the `onPageSelected` callback is not triggered?

I've been attempting to use a boolean to ignore the next selection, like so:

```
ignore = true;
tab.select(); // or viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true); in the case of the swipe
ignore = false;
```

But it seems as though the tab selections and swipe actions are not immediate. AKA the ignore flag is set and unset before the actual selection even takes place.

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

**Tab selection in `ActionBar`:**
Try [`setSelectedNavigationItem(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29) if you already have `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS)`, which I suggest if you would like to use tabs in your `ActionBar`.

**Page selection in `ViewPager`:**
You may use [`setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29) to go to a different page in the `ViewPager` without direct user interaction. Set `smoothScroll` to `true` if you would like to animate the scrolling.